# how to set for loop with two conditions

Tags: r, for-loop

I wrote this for loop to calculate markers in seurat in R code.
`seurat.integrated$res.01` are `"C0"` to `"C5"`. I need to calculate markers for each cluster.
The point is that I need to change, for each cycle, the nr of                               `list[[]]$gene`, because each element of the list correspond to a cluster. so for C0 the nr of `list[[]]` should be 1, for C1 should be 2 and so on. How can I write that in the loop? Thanks!

```
for (i in seurat.integrated$res.01) {
  results <- FindMarkers(seurat.integrated,
                         ident.1 = paste(i, "day4", sep = "_"),
                         ident.2 = paste(i, "day6", sep = "_"),
                         features = list[[]]$gene,
                         logfc.threshold = -Inf,
                         test.use = "wilcox",
                         min.pct = 0.2,
                         min.cells.group = 0,
                         )

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having your data: It seems like the problem can be solved by using `which()` to get the numeric index of a vector.

Note: This only works as intended if each of C0, C1, C2 ... etc. is occurring only once.

```r
clusters <- c("C0", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5")
li <- list(a = "a", b = "b", c = "c", d = "d", e = "e", f = "f")

for (i in clusters) {
  index <- which(clusters == i)
  li[[index]] |> print()
}
#> [1] "a"
#> [1] "b"
#> [1] "c"
#> [1] "d"
#> [1] "e"
#> [1] "f"
```

Edit: And please do not use `list` as a variable name, as this clashes with the function name `list()`. This is why I chose `li`. As a rule of thumb, never use names of functions as variable names, to avoid confusion.